# How do we use JWT tokens for system to system calls for scheduled operations?

Tags: jwt, cron-task

We have an app that let's a user sign in and generate an excel report. User would fill in details then submit. These details would first get saved in the DB and would be fetched at a later time by a cron job to create the excel reports. By this time maybe the user already logged out.

During creation of Excel report the system calls an API to fetch data to put to the Excel report, and this API requires JWT token.

What is the best practice for this kind of scenario? Do we create a JWT token when the user logs in and creates a report and then save the JWT token in the database together with the report details to be fetched later and sent to the API?